# Pip install doesn't work on m1 Mac

Tags: macos, python, homebrew

My pip isn't working. I tried installing it with *ensurepip* as well as with the official *get-pip.py* script. With the official installation script I get a warning:

```
WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.9 are installed in '/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

The end of the script:

```
Successfully installed pip-22.0.4
```

But after restarting Terminal and rebooting it still is not working

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you define "not working"? That phrase is a **very** broad problem description. It would be appropriate to include an error message which leads you to the assumption that "it doesn't work".

Comment: fabian@MacBook-Pro-von-Fabian / % pip --help
zsh: command not found: pip

Comment: Did you install with Homebrew?

Comment: Indeed i installed it with Homebrew and ty @mashuptwice i played around with the PATH, but it didn't helped even after rebooting several times after adding new directories to the Path. I setup a clean Monterey as dualboot: I installed Homebrew and then Python, but pip didn't work after all.

Comment: @fabolous05 note that you can always run a command by changing to its directory and running the script with `./scriptname`

Comment: I know that? @mashuptwice
But i recognized that in my second Monterey, I set up as dualboot, i can open all Applications i installed on my other Monterey. The purpose of setting up a new Monterey ^^is a new clean installation^^, can my main Monterey still effect this? Should I actually be able to open the other apps? Isn't that a huge security gap?

Comment: @fabolous05 If you know that you can run scripts by specifying their whole path, why don't you include in neither your question nor in your comment if it works or not to start pip that way?
 To this point the only pieces of information about your issue are "doesn't work", "didn't work" and "didn't helped". It is impossible to find out the cause of your problem with that level of detail.

About your dualboot: that is way outside the scope of your original question. You might want to search or ask on askdifferent about that issue.

Answer (score 6):

I am really sorry for this question

I just recognized that i have to type pip3

Comment: You could create an alias for `pip` pointing to `pip3` via `alias pip=pip3` for convenience.

Comment: pip3 is fine i just couldn't run pip/pip3 that was my problem
anyways thank you for your input

Answer (score 3):

The error message `WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.9 are installed in '/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH` tells you all you need to know about the issue and solution.

You need to modify your `$PATH` variable as following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin
```

You can find information about making the change permanent [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install python `brew install python3` it will install python and pip, pip3 to the machine